# How to close an app correctly on desktop?

Tags: java, libgdx

When I use `Gdx.app.exit()` the game window closes but the resources don't appear to be released and the app is still running.

For instance, to exit on when the escape key is pressed:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

//...

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE))
        Gdx.app.exit();
```

The window closes, the `dispose()` method is called but Eclipse still reports that the app is open (because the terminate button is still available):
[image: Eclipse reports that the app is still running]

If the app had exited properly, the path to the JVM would have `<terminated`> in front of it, and the red terminate button would be greyed out.

Also when I use `hide()` and then `dispose()`:

```
@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    map.dispose();
    ...
    playerHitbox.dispose();
    System.out.println("----- END OF OUTPUT -----");

}
```

The same thing happens. You have to terminate the app with the button provided by Eclipse, or in the release version use the `kill` command (or task manager).

So my question is, how can I properly exit the app so all resources are gracefully unloaded, the window hides and the process exits in LibGDX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution!

In my `DesktopLauncher` class, I had set `config.forceExit` to `false` instead of `true`, which caused the app to exit incorrectly (keep the running in the background.)

[image: You need to set config.forceExit to true]

And there are no AL lib cleanup errors or native-related libraries having issues.

Comment: Thanks, it still works on 2021! That line of code must be placed after `LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();`
 Also I checked in terminal that there isn't anymore the process active.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `System.exit(0);` should do the trick. Depending on your project setup, `Gdx.app.exit();` could be terminating the LibGDX app, and not the entire program, where an added system exit will kill the runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried System.exit(0) and while it does work it gives me an `AL lib: alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed` error, which I've read is harmless but I'd prefer to exit the app without any errors. I'll use this as a temporary fix in the mean time. Thanks ;)

Comment: It's now giving my other errors like: `pure virtual method called [new line]
terminate called without an active exception` so I think I'll avoid it.